# Android Emulator deploy speed

Tags: xamarin.forms, android-emulator, prism

I'm not sure whether this is the right place for my question. If not, please close the thread.

I'm new to Xamarin.Forms/Mobile development. (not to .NET development in general).

Anyway, when I deploy my very basic sandbox/test  app which uses Xamarin Prism (currently only 2 Views and ViewModels) to the Android Emulator, it takes about 2-3 minutes to start the app. I'm working on an Lenovo X1 Yoga (2nd GEN), with a Core i7 7300U, 8GB RAM and SSD. So I can't imagine the specs are to low. I also enabled virtualization in the BIOS.

Is the time it takes to deploy really that long?

I can't imagine how this will go once the application grows?

Is there sometihng I can try t improve the performance, or is this behaviour normal?

Kind Regards

Gilles

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/

Comment: @EvZ thanks to the docs you posted (troubleshooting section), I found that I had both Hyper-V and HAXM installed/activated. I now disabled Hyper-V and it seems to have helped